# allure does not show reports from previous report

Tags: report, history, allure

I need to store history from previous reports, but in allure can see only last one.
Before generate latest report I copied history folder from previous.
So, folder structure:

```
➜  ui-tests git:(master) ✗ ll allure-results
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 k  staff    96B May  7 18:10 history
-rw-r--r--  1 k  staff   293B May  7 09:53 report.xml
```

Then I run:

```
allure generate -o allure-results -c allure-report --clean
```

and

```
allure open -h localhost -p 8083
```

and see this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZnrU.png)

When I decided to generate from previous report ( files what I have after every test run. And see this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKRDr.png)

Why, when copying, I do not see the history, but when I generate it from several reports, I see it?

Comment: maybe it doesn't matter, but I using this in gitlab-pages and work in separate branch (not master)

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to achieve? The first image shows history correctly in the trends section (top right). The second shows a number of test suites but no history.

Comment: I need to see statistics on the last runs of tests, how many tests worked, how many of them failed. I found this [gitlab-allure-history](https://gitlab.com/aleksandr-kotlyar/gitlab-allure-history), but I don't like because I want to store all reports of all branches in main page of allure report

Answer (score 0):

Your command looks wrong to me.

I would call

- allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report

History works perfectly. Ping me if you have an issue still.